# How to Get Sessionkey by using Facebook javascript API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am Using the following code to use Fconnect in my website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php" ></script>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    FB_RequireFeatures(["XFBML"], function () {
        FB.init(MY_App_ID, Domain_Path + "xd_receiver.htm");
    });
</script>


<fb:login-button length='short' size='medium' onlogin="facebook_onlogin_ready()" ></fb:login-button>
```

previously the following code was returning the Session Key but now its not.

```
FB.Facebook.apiClient.get_session()
```

its giving Undefined error
How i can get User SessionKey using the Facebook Jascript Api.

Comment: This is the old legacy js sdk, facebook urges everyone to upgrade to the new one: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/oldjavascript/.

Answer (score 0):

That code is using a deprecated API which is no longer supported and could be removed at any time as it's scheduled for deletion.

The current [Javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) uses OAuth access tokens, not session keys.